# Insertar multiples rows en un solo INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema, quiero cargar de una forma mas rápida información a mi base de datos, actualmente quiero cargar cerca de 7100 registros, el problema es que hago un insert por cada uno de ellos y se vuelve un poco lento, quiero intentar mejorar la velocidad de registro ejecutando un insert con múltiples valores, actualmente el registro de datos lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
foreach ($productosIngram as $key => $value) {

                    $connect->beginTransaction();

                    $stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO productos_domar(sku, codigo_barras, codigo_fabricante, titulo, id_marca, id_categoria, length, width, height, weight, status) VALUES (:sku, :codigo_barras, :codigo_fabricante, :titulo, :id_marca, :id_categoria, :length, :width, :height, :weight, :status)");

                    $stmt->execute([':sku' => $value['sku'],
                                    ':codigo_barras' => $value['codigo_barras'],
                                    ':codigo_fabricante' => $value['codigo_fabricante'],
                                    ':titulo' => $value['titulo'],
                                    ':id_marca' => $value['id_marca'],
                                    ':id_categoria' => $value['id_categoria'],
                                    ':length' => $value['length'],
                                    ':width' => $value['width'],
                                    ':height' => $value['height'],
                                    ':weight' => $value['weight'],
                                    ':status' => $value['status'],
                                   ]);

                    $connect->commit();
```

Pero si lo hago de esta forma tarda un poco, el problema es que no se como puedo hacer un insert con multiples rows para que este proceso sea mas rápido, como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Las sentencias preparadas se pueden usar múltiples veces. Empieza con poner `$connect->beginTransaction();  $stmt = $connect->prepare(...);` **antes del ciclo foreach(){ }** y has un solo conmit luego de cerrar el ciclo. Notarás una mejora de rendimiento bastante significativa.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ir acumulando registros e insertarlos cuando se llegue a cierta cantidad, para generar consultas del tipo:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (columna1, columna2, columnaX) VALUES
    (valor1, valor2, valorX),
    (valor1, valor2, valorX),
    (valor1, valor2, valorX)
```

Solo hay algunos detalles a tener en cuenta:

- Como ya te mencionaron en comentarios, es recomendable hacer todo en una sola transacción y un solo *commit*
- Los parámetros no pueden ser por nombre, sino por marcador `?`
- Hay un límite para la cantidad de registros que se pueden insertar, pero depende de la longitud de los datos y, seguramente, de la memoria disponible; creé una variable `$registros` para que puedas modificar y probar hasta obtener los mejores resultados y evitar cualquier posible error
- Se deben crear algunas variables adicionales para:

  - Crear la consulta
  - Acumular marcadores y valores
  - Contar los registros acumulados para ejecutar la consulta

```
          // Una sola transacción
          $connect->beginTransaction();
          // Crear cadena para consulta, sin valores ni parámetros
          $sql = 'INSERT INTO productos_domar(sku, codigo_barras, codigo_fabricante, titulo, id_marca, id_categoria, length, width, height, weight, status) VALUES ';
          // En lugar de parámetros con nombre, se van a usar por marcadores
          $sqlMarks = '(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
          // Inicializar arreglo de marcadores y valores
          $marks = [];
          $values = [];
          // Inicializar cuenta
          $cuenta = 0;
          // Insertar cuando se tenga esta cantidad de registros
          $registros = 20;
          // Total de registros a insertar
          $max = count($productosIngram);
          foreach ($productosIngram as $key => $value) {
                // Agregar marcadores y valores a sus respectivos arreglos
                $marks[] = $sqlMarks;
                array_push($values,
                    $value['sku'],
                    $value['codigo_barras'],
                    $value['codigo_fabricante'],
                    $value['titulo'],
                    $value['id_marca'],
                    $value['id_categoria'],
                    $value['length'],
                    $value['width'],
                    $value['height'],
                    $value['weight'],
                    $value['status']
                );
                // Incrementar contador
                $cuenta ++;
                // Si el contador es múltiplo de la cantidad de registros a insertar
                // O se está procesando el último registro
                if(($cuenta % $registros) == 0 || $cuenta == $max) {
                    // Armar consulta agregando marcadores para la cantidad de registros obtenidos
                    $stmt = $connect->prepare($sql . implode(', ', $marks));
                    // Ejecutar agregando valores
                    $stmt->execute($values);
                    // Reinicializar arreglos de marcadores y valores
                    $marks = [];
                    $values = [];
                }
          }
          // Solo un commit
          $connect->commit();
```

**Nota:** Desconozco si `$key` es el índice numérico del arreglo `$productos`; si es el caso, seguramente se pueden omitir las variables para contador y máximo de registros, pero ya es un detalle mínimo.